# What is the "base" file that the Bokeh index.html extends?

Tags: jinja2, bokeh

I am a little confused about what  `{% extends base %}` is extending at the start of `index.html` in Bokeh server application packages.

Examples of this can be seen in:

- [Bokeh Docs: Embedding in Templates](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-figures-in-the-template)

```
{% extends base %}

{% block contents %}
<div>
    <p> Hello {{ user_id }}, AKA '{{ last_name }}, {{ first_name }}'! </p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

- [Bokeh Server Application Examples](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html#server-app-examples)
  Example code from the Gapminder package in templates/index.html

```
{% extends base %}

{% block title %}Bokeh Gapminder Example{% endblock %}

{% block postamble %}
  <style>
    {% include 'styles.css' %}
  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

What is this "base" that is being extended?

I see that there is a "contents" block, "title" block, and "postamble" block from the above examples.
How do I know what other jinja blocks I can modify?

Thanks.

Comment: It's in the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html?highlight=postamble#standard-template

Comment: actually its here : https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html#